# Attempting to rewrite a Discord.py GIF Bot from an old outdated guide

Tags: discord.py

Ok, so I'm attempting to rebuild a GIF bot in Discord.py.

It is based off of some code found on a website that gave a guide on making a `discord.py` gif bot.

The problem is, the code is old and severely outdated with over 37 errors on it's own.

How would I go about converting this to `discord.py-rewrite` and basically making it a gif searching bot that can pick up random gifs by tag from GIPHY?

Here is the code I currently have:

```
import discord.utils
import os
import giphy_client
from giphy_client.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

API_KEY = os.getenv("GIPHY_API_KEY")
API_TOKEN = os.getenv("GIPHY_API_TOKEN")

api_instance = giphy_client.DefaultApi()
config = {
    'api_key': API_KEY,
    'token': API_TOKEN,
    'limit': 1,
    'rating': 'g'
}

try:
    api_response = api_instance.gifs_trending_get(
        config['token'], limit=config['limit'], rating=config['rating'])
    pprint(api_response)

except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling DefaultApi->gifs_trending_get: %s\n" % e)

Client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=os.getenv("CLIENT_PREFIX"))


class DiscordClient(discord.Client):


    @Client.event
    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Connected to Discord Client as")
        print(f'{self.user.name}#{self.user.discriminator}')
        print("-------")

    @Client.command(name="gif")
    async def search_gifs(query):
        try:
            giphy_token = API_TOKEN
            response = api_instance.gifs_search_get(giphy_token, query, limit=3, rating='g')
            lst = list(response.data)
            gif = random.choices(lst)

            return gif[0].url

        except ApiException as e:
            return "Exception when calling DefaultApi->gifs_search_get: %s\n" % e

    async def on_ready(self):
        print("Connected to Discord Client as")
        print(Client.user.name)
        print("-------")

    @Client.command(name='gif')
    async def search_gifs(query):
        try:
            response = api_instance.gifs_search_get(
                API_TOKEN, query, limit=3, rating='g')
            lst = list(response.data)
            gif = random.choices(lst)
            return gif[0].url
            except ApiException as e:\
                return "Exception when calling DefaultApi->gifs_search_get: %s\n" % e\


    @Client.command(name='8ball')
    async def magic_eight_ball(ctx):
        response = [
            'Without a doubt.',
            'Outlook good.',
            'Better not tell you now.',
            'Cannot predict now.',
            'My reply is no.',
            'Outlook not so good.',
        ]
        gif = await search_gifs('cheese')
        await ctx.send(random.choice(response))
        await ctx.send('Gif URL : ' + gif)


Client.run(os.getenv("CLIENT_TOKEN"))
```

Here is the website I got the code I'm building off of from:

https://www.maxongzb.com/serving-gifs-with-discord-bot-reading-time-12-mins/

Here is what I currently have for the  `requirements.txt` file:

```
discord.py
giphy_client
python-dotenv
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

I host via Heroku due to my VPS taking a dump, so that's why I have the `os.getenv("...")` lines in there.

I've gotten it down to around 7 errors, 8 warnings and 8 weak warnings. But that's the furthest I was able to get to.

Comment: dude check this [question making guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please, it's to long and nobody would actually answer this kind of questions.

Comment: Reformatted the question.

Comment: What kind of errors are you experiencing?

Comment: Basically as it is it doesn't even run and PyCharm has spotted at least 7 errors still remaining as well as 8 warnings and 8 weak warnings. I'm hoping to at least get it to work basically.